# How to plot multiple data one after another in the same graph using Python Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I was trying to visualize a facebook stock dataset, where the data for 2014 to 2018 is stored. The dataset looks like this: [dataset screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzTsF.png)

My goal is to visualize the closing column, but by year. That is, year 2014, then 2015 and so on, but they should be in one figure, and one after another. Something like this: [expected graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXn7q.png)

But whatever I try, all the graph parts start from index 0, instead of continuing from the end of the previous one. Here's what I got: [the graph I generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh8Fa.png)

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post some data and your code in text form? That would make it much easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is simply to create separate dataframes with empty 
values for the non-needed dates.

Here I use an example dataset.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0, 100, size=100),
    index=pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01", periods=100, freq="D"),
)
```

Then you can create and select the data to plot

```py
df1 = df.copy()
df2 = df.copy()

df1[df.index > pd.to_datetime('2020-02-01')] = np.NaN
df2[df.index < pd.to_datetime('2020-02-01')] = np.NaN
```

And then simply plot these on the same axis.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(18, 8))

ax.plot(df1)
ax.plot(df2)
```

The result

[image]